# how to change "product details" text to my own text in Virtuemart?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, virtuemart

How can I change the "Product details" text to a text of my own like only "Product", in a Joomla Virtuemart installation? example [here](http://www.exclusivdeal.ro/index.php/produse)

I've tried looking in the used template's css files but didn't find anything right to modify or add. And also I've looked in the administrator panel of Joomla Virtuemart, but no option there neither.

[image: what's in the red circles]

Comment: link you shared is dead!

Comment: i don't think it is... what country are you from? check here http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/exclusivdeal.ro.html

Comment: I'm from India we can't access the url.

Comment: I've had this problem before with indian workers on Freelancer, who couldn't access romanian domains... I don't know why (anyway I've uploaded an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Its a text that comes from the language file, You can find the file on the following path.

```
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini

COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS="Product details"
```

Just change these text with what ever you want..

Its a core edit keep in mind while the VM UPDATION.

Hope it works..

Comment: sorry i missed that file name en-GB.com_virtuemart

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :) it worked perfectly! do you maybe know how to get rid of the text displayed in the top right corner "Attention no standard shopper group set" ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: This may happen due to no default shopper groups in VM or current logged in users is not assigned to any shopper groups. So check admin->VM->Orders and shoppers->shopper groups-> Make sure one default shopper group is available for the Shop. Also check if current users have proper groups.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the language.ini file, I would suggest you use a Language Override. The problem with editing the file is that if and when you decide to install an update for VirtueMart, you will lose your changes.

To perform a Language Override:

1. Login to your Joomla backend
2. On the top menu, go to **Extensions** >> **Language Manager**
3. Click on the **Overrides** tab. then click **New**
4. In the field *Language Constant*, type in **COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS**
5. In the *Text* field, type in **Product** which is what the button text will be replaced with.

Hope this helps

Comment: this didn't work, but i managed to do it in another way. do you maybe know how to get rid of the text displayed in the top right corner "Attention no standard shopper group set" ? thank you in advance :)